# TypeError: Object of type ManyRelatedManager is not JSON serializable in django rest framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, primary-key, django-serializer

I am trying to add some students to a teacher class using their ids as primary key but I am getting above error.

I have  models of Teachers and Students like this.

```
class Student(TimeStampAbstractModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="student", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    college_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name

class Teacher(TimeStampAbstractModel):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name="teacher", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)
    students_in_class = models.ManyToManyField(Student,related_name="teacher")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.name
```

Here a teacher model can have many students in a class with thier ids. I have used an put api call to add the students to the teacher in one click.

My view:

```
from rest_framework import status
class AddtoClassView(APIView):
    

    def put(self,request,pk,*args,**kwargs):
        id =pk
        teacher = Teacher.objects.get(id=id)
        serializer = TeacherSerializer(teacher,data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            print("iam if")
            return Response({
                "message":"Student has been added to class.",
                "data": serializer.data
            },status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

        # else:
        print("iam else")
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My serializer:

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students_in_class = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only= True
    )
    address = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    # user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ["address","students_in_class"]
        # fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.address = validated_data.get("address")
        instance.save()
        stu = validated_data.get("students_in_class")
        print(stu)
        if stu is not None:
            print("iam stu")
            instance.students_in_class.add(stu)
        instance.save()
        super(TeacherSerializer,self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Here I have used students_in_class as pk field ( i still havent understand when to use integarfield and when to use pk field). I know since i am adding the ids to the student_in_class field i am not supposed to use it as `read_only = true`, however i had to use otherwise it generates error. How to solve this? Also, i dont really know which fields to define as which in serializer class.

**Updated code:**

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # students_in_class = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
    #     many = True, read_only= True
    # )
    students_in_class = serializers.ListField(
        source="students_in_class.all",
        child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all()),
    )
    address = serializers.CharField(required=False)
    # user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ["address","students_in_class"]
        # fields = '__all__'

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.address = validated_data['students_in_class']['all']
        instance.save()
        stu = validated_data.get("students_in_class")
        print(stu)
        if stu is not None:
            print("iam stu")
            instance.students_in_class.add(stu)
        instance.save()
        super(TeacherSerializer,self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Comment: Please don't insert "EDIT"s/"UPDATE"s, just make your post the best presentation as of edit time. But--Please do not edit a question post in a way that invalidates reasonable answer posts; if there are reasonable answers then fix the old post to ask its question & post a new question. Don't edit answers into question posts, post an answer. PS This post doesn't say what this "Updated code" has to do with the question you are asking. [ask] [Help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code worked:

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students_in_class = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many = True,queryset=Student.objects.all()
    )
    address = serializers.CharField(required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Teacher
        fields = ["address","students_in_class"]


    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        instance.address = validated_data.get("address")
        instance.save()
        stu = validated_data.pop("students_in_class")

        for stus in stu:
            instance.students_in_class.add(stus)

        instance.save()
        super(TeacherSerializer,self).update(instance, validated_data)
        return instance
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using m2m field, you need list of ids for `students_in_class`. So the solution will be something like this. (Disclaimer: Code not tested).

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students_in_class = serializers.ListField(
        source="students_in_class.all", 
        child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all()),
    )
```

Serialization error will be solved because now you have included `students_in_class.all` as source. You need to access the data with something like this: `validated_data['students_in_class']['all']`

If you want to serialize your output in different way, you could  set `students_in_class` as `write_only` and override serializer representation as needed.:

```
class TeacherSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    students_in_class = serializers.ListField(
        child=serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Student.objects.all()),
        write_only=True
    )
    # your code

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['students_in_class'] = StudentSerializer(instance.students_in_class.all(), many=True).data
        return ret
```

Comment: I have updated the answer.

Comment: I got the error saying TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got {'all': [<Student: Student1>]}.
 after trying your code...can you look

Comment: Show your updated code.

Comment: Just remember now you should get list of objects  in validated_data[students_in_class]['all']. Modify your code accordingly.

Comment: Hello i have updated the code can you check?

Comment: Why are you doing  `instance.address = validated_data['students_in_class']['all']` ? It was fine before. You need to do change this one         stu = `validated_data.get("students_in_class")`
 to most likely `stu = validated_data['students_in_class']['all']`. Please do `print(validated_data)` and see how data is recieved, and modify your code accordingly. It's possible there might be some extra work to be done.

Comment: sorry, it was a typo. I had put it on stu not on address...but still i got same error. Also can you tell me when to use source and this listserializer,??

Comment: pop/remove  ['students_in_class']['all']  from vailidated data after/while assigniing to stu. Do not pass it below.

Comment: I printed the validataed_data and got this {'address': 'prague', 'students_in_class': {'all': [<Student: Student2>]}}

Comment: Now pop that `students_in_class` and use however you want. May be you want to loop over students and add them. Or, may be you just want to   do            `instance.students_in_class.set(stu)`. Its your choice.  Just don't forget to pop/remove `students_in_class`  from validated data .

Comment: pop and get is similar, in my oprinion. I used get from validated data to get the ids and used add if you see my earlier code.

Comment: pop will remove the key from dictionary. get won't. We want the key to be removed after it is used.

Comment: ok one question,  I am sending just a id 2,3 like this in json however if I print i got like this'students_in_class': {'all': [<Student: Student2>]}} is this ok??

Comment: Yes. Correct. You will get list of students in that way.

Comment: If you follow the second approach from my answer. You will get list of students without that extra `all`. Whatever  you feel okay, you can do that.

Comment: Hello, I have posted my answer which worked. I didnt use Listfield, source and child and I am not too sure when to use these...i am glad and thankful you made efforts for my question

Comment: No problem. Use Listfield and child , when you need multiple students in the API request. Since, you are adding student one at a time, you do not need it. If you want to add multiple students in a single API, you will need them.

Comment: Furthermore, if you need to list all the students data during GET, then you can do it using the source field. The source is basically telling that the return value for `students_in_class`  should be `instance.students_in_class.all()`.

Comment: hello my friend, i can add multiple students at the same time with my code. The for loop that i have used is doing the work. so ...??

Comment: Can you show code with for loop?

Comment: `for stus in stu:`
     `instance.students_in_class.add(stus)` ..This loop helps add all the ids sent from the frontend. Its working.. whats your opinion on this...isnt it so?

Comment: Oh, I see you included `many=True` here. `students_in_class = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many = True,queryset=Student.objects.all())`.  There might be  might be some fields where you cannot do this and might have to resort to ListField and child.  For example, try to do `CharField(many=True)` It might not work.But in this case, it seems you need not do so.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238304/discussion-between-django-rocks-and-sagar-adhikari).